# Hibernate cant create entity manager factory

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

Hello my spring boot application wont start with MySql database.Maybe my mappings are not OK?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tweets")
public class Tweet {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long tweetId;

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private User userId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "tweet")
    private Collection<Like> likes;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String content;

    private long score;

    public Tweet(){}

    public Tweet(User user, String content) {
        this.userId = user;
        this.content = content;
        this.score = 0;
    }

    public long getTweetId() {
        return tweetId;
    }

    public long getUserId() {
        return userId.getUserId();
    }

    public Collection<Like> getLikes() {
        return likes;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public long getScore() {
        return score;
    }
}
```

Here is User table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long userId;

    private String email;

    @JsonIgnore
    private String password;

    private String www;

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "userId", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Collection<Tweet> tweets;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "userId", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Collection<Like> likes;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(User user) {
        this.userId = user.getUserId();
        this.email = user.getEmail();
        this.password = user.getPassword();
        this.www = user.getWww();
        this.firstName = user.getFirstName();
        this.lastName = user.getLastName();
    }


    public User(String email, String password, String www, String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.email = email;
//        this.password = BCrypt.hashpw(password,BCrypt.gensalt());
        this.www = www;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public long getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public String getWww() {
        return www;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public Collection<Tweet> getTweets() {
        return tweets;
    }

    public Collection<Like> getLikes() {
        return likes;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "userId=" + userId +
                ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                ", password='" + password + '\'' +
                ", www='" + www + '\'' +
                ", firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
                ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
                ", tweets=" + tweets +
                ", likes=" + likes +
                '}';
    }
}
```

and here is Like table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "likes")
public class Like {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long likeId;

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private User userId;

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "tweet_id", nullable = false)
    private Tweet tweet;

    public Like() {
    }

    public Like(User user, Tweet tweet) {
        this.userId = user;
        this.tweet = tweet;
    }

    public long getLikeId() {
        return likeId;
    }

    public User getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public Tweet getTweet() {
        return tweet;
    }

    public void setLikeId(long likeId) {
        this.likeId = likeId;
    }

    public void setUserId(User userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public void setTweet(Tweet tweet) {
        this.tweet = tweet;
    }
}
```

I have to admit that Im a bit confused because Application boots when I'm using H2 database , but I cant get it working with Mysql. The application.properties file is OK, I chcked It with another project where Im having the same config values.

The error is as follows:

```
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
```

Comment: Can you provide the full stack trace please?

Comment: I solved the problem, it was connected to restricted words in mysql + mapping on Collections caused MultipleBagException from hibernate so i changed it to Set